# I could not get setMap function () hide the markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps

O am creating a record of sites, the process data in php and mysql,
and saved to XML. Everything works fine, but I could not get setMap function () hide the
markers arranged by type.

This is the link: http://planosunab.mentalidadweb.com/?page_id=33

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are calling the function on the array:

```
markersArray.setMap(null);
```

You have to call the function for each marker in the array! ;)